# centering a label in a subview

Tags: ios, swift

those are my first steps with ios

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

// MARK: Properties

@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

// MARK: Events

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    testLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    testLabel.sizeToFit()
    testLabel.center.x = testLabel.superview!.center.x
    //from here the label is centered
}

// MARK: Actions

@IBAction func trackButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //first call: the label is aligned on the left
    //following calls: the label is centered
    testLabel.text = Track.createTrack().toText()
    //even the following commented code does not allow the centering 
    //on the first call

    //testLabel.sizeToFit()
    //testLabel.center.x = testLabel.superview!.center.x
}
}
```

the design is as follow:
[image: design view]

I'm pulling my hair out on this.

============================================================

## updated project

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

// MARK: Properties    
@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

// MARK: Events

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    //testLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    //testLabel.sizeToFit()
    //testLabel.center.x = testLabel.superview!.center.x
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// MARK: Actions

@IBAction func trackButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    testLabel.text = Track.createTrack().toText()
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to setup the constraints interface builder.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Autolayout by setting constraints. In your case in storyboard.

- remove most `testLabel` code visible in your answer:

  class ViewController: UIViewController {

  ```
  // MARK: Properties

  @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!


  // MARK: Actions

  @IBAction func trackButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
  testLabel.text = Track.createTrack().toText()
  }
  ```

  }

In Storyboard:

- Select your `Test Label`
- Delete all contraints of the label:

[image]

Your label looks right. I is of full width because you set the `StackView` allignment to `fill`:

[image]

You can set this to `center`, but this will affect the all views within the `stackView` also. If this is not acceptatble, mover the label out of the stack view.

Also, you want to center the text of the `UILabel, using the labels`Alignment` property:

[image]

Comment: it has no effect but expanding the label width and so keeping the text on the left.

Comment: Can you link to the project. Updated answer.

Comment: If the constraints on the label are expanding to fill the width and you are still seeing left aligned text, have you checked central alignment in Interface builder to center it within this central space?

Comment: @shallowThought done, but the centered Label text id due to a center text (a fallback temporary solution).